# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream retornando pdf

Tags: c#, .net-core

estoy poniendo contraseña a un pdf que generé previamente, hace todo el proceso bien pero haciendo debug tengo este error:

**System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream**

el codigo que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
public HtmlToPdfResponse ConvertHtmlToPdfOutPassword(HtmlToPdfRequest request)
        {
            HtmlToPdfResponse pdfOutPassword = new HtmlToPdfResponse();
            GlobalSettings globalSettings = new GlobalSettings()
            {
                ColorMode = new ColorMode?(ColorMode.Color),
                Orientation = new Orientation?(Orientation.Portrait),
                PaperSize = (PechkinPaperSize)PaperKind.A4,
                Margins = new MarginSettings()
                {
                    Top = new double?(18.0),
                    Bottom = new double?(18.0)
                }
            };
            ObjectSettings objectSettings = new ObjectSettings()
            {
                PagesCount = new bool?(true),
                HtmlContent = request.Html,
                WebSettings =
                {
          DefaultEncoding = "utf-8"
                },
                HeaderSettings =
                {
          FontSize = new int?(10),
          Right = "Pagína [page] de [toPage]",
          Line = new bool?(false)
                }
            };
            byte[] buffer = _converter.Convert((IDocument)new HtmlToPdfDocument()
            {
                GlobalSettings = globalSettings,
                Objects =
                {
          objectSettings
                }
            });
            byte[] passwordpropietario = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request.UserPassword);
            byte[] passwordusuario = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request.UserPassword);
            EncryptionProperties properties = new EncryptionProperties();
            properties.SetStandardEncryption(passwordusuario, passwordpropietario, EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING | EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_ASSEMBLY, EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_256);
            string str = (string)null;
          

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(ms).SetSmartMode(true)))
            {
                // Create reader from bytes
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                {
                    // Create reader from bytes
                    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(memoryStream))
                    {
                        PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, ms, properties);
                        str = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                        pdfOutPassword.PdfBase64 = str;
                        return pdfOutPassword; **Error aquí**
                    }
                }
            }
         
        }
```

No se si tenga que ver, pero estoy usando una librería para generar el pdf a través de un string HTMl y otra librería para ponerle contraseña.la documentacion de la librecia dice que debo usar el pdf.close() donde se está cerrando el using, pero el visual studio me marca ese error no controlado, lo he movido de lugar y usando otros comandos similares al close pero no funciona, tambien intento comentar la linea pdf.close() y tengo el mismo error en el corchete siguiente que cierra

Comment: Existe un `pdf.IsOpen`? Si es así, por qué no le haces un `if(pdf.IsOpen) pdf.Close()`. Recuerda que estás utilizando un `using`, que obliga al recolector de basura a desechar ese objeto cuando sale del scope

Comment: Es que el error es No se puede acceder a un Stream cerrado entonces no se cual steram este cerrado porque no he serrado ninguno hasta ahi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la parte de los using borré el using que no se está usando:

```
        using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(ms).SetSmartMode(true)))
        {
        }
```